# Change Python method parameter name programmatically

Tags: python, parameters

**I am not looking to change the actual signature of the method**

**I do not want to create a new method with new parameter names**

How can I modify a parameter's name in a method's signature?

I am creating an abstract class for a Spark Streaming job on a custom internal framework which requires one of the parameter names to match the Kafka topic's name or else it will pick up the argument as an optional flag.

Here is the method in question:

```
 def apply(self, sc, records):

    if not self.FILTER_FIELDS:
        raise Exception('SalesForceTransformStage requires FILTER_FIELDS:[_label_,[_values_]]')

    return shipping_label \
        .filter(lambda rec: rec[self.FILTER_FIELDS[0]] in self.FILTER_FIELDS[1]) \
        .filter(self.filters) \
        .map(lambda rdd: format_record_keys_for_salesforce(rdd,
                                                           self.SALESFORCE_FIELD_MAP,
                                                           self.SALESFORCE_FIELD_LIMITS,
                                                           self.INPUTS[self.INPUTS.keys()[0]])) \
        .map(self.mappers) \
        .map(self.OUTPUT.project_row)
```

Right now, the parameter `records` is being picked up as a optional flag, so when I run the script, this happens:

```
usage: new_shipping_label_event.py [-h] [--force-rebuild] --records RECORDS
                               [--save-to SAVE_TO]
new_shipping_label_event.py: error: argument --records is required
```

However, changing the argument name to be `shipping_label` (the name of the kafka topic), runs the script fine. How can I programmatically set a parameter's name?

Comment: Can I suggest you define those `lambda`s ahead of time (possibly private methods) so that the filtering is not a single "line" that needs to span over 9 to be readable.

Comment: No, why would that make it any more readable?

Comment: Is that an example or the actual function? I was assuming the actual one was more complicated and the several filtering was embedded inside but if that is the entire method then nevermind.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Ah I see what you mean, this is the abstraction for a more complicated, if you want, I can add it as an edit but it wouldn't be very necessary.

Comment: no no, meant for your actual code, the example is quite clear!

Answer (score 2):

give `records` a default value so it is optional.

```
def apply(self, sc, records=None):
```

Comment: No, making it optional does nothing since the super class checks that arguments line up with Kafka topic names. I thought I made that clear enough.

Comment: can you put more code, like the implementation of the class

Comment: Probably not? Just cus these are internally built spark streaming frameworks. All you guys have to know is that the apply method's signature has to have the form `(self, sc, *kafka topic name*)`

Comment: Look at this link https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/. *args and **kwargs arguments may help you

Comment: No, because the method signature condition will not be satisfied. Are you fully understanding the issue? If not, I'de be glad to clarify anything.

Comment: @ylun.ca if giving the argument a default value does not let your program realize that it is not required, that sounds like a fairly fundamental flaw in the library you are using for automating the arguments.  The only way to programmably change the parameter names is to manually create the `code` object, the documentation on it (`help(types.CodeType)`) is literally just "Not for the faint of heart." so I highly recommend *against* that route.

Comment: it is possible to modify the file new_shipping_label_event.py?

Comment: Thanks guys. Yea its not much of a flaw as it is a feature to make sure the jobs that we run are easy to piece together. I've actually just made the abstract class have a signature of `def apply(self, sc, records):` and then in my concrete class, have ```def apply(self, sc, shipping_label):
        return super(NewShippingLabelEvent, self).apply(sc, shipping_label)```

Ugly, but hey, it works now.